# Is there music theoretical 'pattern' in ending themes?

Tags: scales

I don't know if I should ask this here or in https://musicfans.stackexchange.com . I'm also not sure if the wording of my question is fine. So feel free to suggest corrections.

I tend to like ending themes in series, cartoons, animes, games etc more than the rest of the tracks. I might be wrong, but it seems to me they usually have the same feel. I wonder if it has a well understood musical theory behind it. Does it exist?

Some examples:

Dungeons and dragons cartoon ending:

Jaspion tokusatsu ending:

Yuyu Hakusho anime first ending -

Comment: Huh, I normally find credits themes in video games to be longer, more bloated, and *less* appealing than their opening themes and title themes.

Comment: @Dekkadeci the question isn't about taste or how good they are, though.